# How to exclude the summaryType from the jqGrid while Exporting to excel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, export-to-excel

I am using jqGrid version **jqGrid JS - v5.3.0**

This is the Action Column in jqGrid where summaryType is given

```
{label: 'Action', name: 'ACTION', width: 60
     , summaryType: function (val, name, record) {
          return "Grand Total Printed:<br /> Grand Total Void:<br /> Grand Total Remaining :"                 
          }
},



        $("#headerJqGrid").jqGrid("exportToExcel", {
        title: 'Bl Print Control Header',
        includeLabels: true,
        includeGroupHeader: true,
        includeFooter: true,
        fileName: "HeaderSearchRecords.xlsx",
        maxlength: 40,
    });
```

This is the exportToExcel function used. How do I **exclude** the **summaryType** from display when I **export to excel**

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities.
The first one is to disable the footer row where the summary should appear:

```
    $("#headerJqGrid").jqGrid("exportToExcel", {
    ...
       includeFooter: false,
    ...
});
```

The second one is to return empty string with global flag in case you bind a click button to export to excel

```
var export_summary= true;
....
$("#mybutton").on("click", function(){
    export_summary= false;
    $("#headerJqGrid").jqGrid("exportToExcel", {...});
    export_summary= true;
});
```

and in the summarType

```
 , summaryType: function (val, name, record) {
      return export_summary ? "Grand Total Printed:<br /> Grand Total Void:<br /> Grand Total Remaining :" ? "";                 
      }
```

Comment: Hi Tony Thanks for your effort , but I tried both the possibilities but couldnt achieve it. Can you help me out with any other way?

Comment: I do not think that the first option should be demonstrated. Just set it to false and your footer totals will not be displayed. Will prepare a example for the second case.

Comment: @Benazir Here is a [example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/exceltest/) which does not export the summary type when export to excel

Comment: Hi Tony in my case when the exportToexcel function is called the grid is not loaded with value as export_summary = false, hence I'm retained with the same values. What is the way to refresh the colmodel in my case

Comment: To update the colModel item use setColProp method. See docs.